# Clear all DataGridView selection in all Tabs on Form Load

Tags: c#, .net

I have **2** Tabs.

Each tab contain a **1** **DataGridView**.

In a Form_Load I putted two functions

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
```

But, on form load, work only one, and this one stay in the first active Tab 1.

**The question is :** How to clear all **DataGridView** in all tabs on form load ?

Comment: Can you post the complete code and markup? Which one does work on the sample code you posted (Was it Grid1 or Grid2)?

Comment: Create 2 tabs, put for each tab one DataGridView, and on Form Load try to unselect all rows in all DataGridView in each Tab.  The dataGridView1.ClearSelection(); works on Form Load, only for FIRST active tab (Tab1), and do not for any other in our case Tab2.

Comment: Given that you mentioned that your Tab1 is your current active tab and the `ClearSelection()` method works, then likely the second command, `dataGridView2.ClearSelection();` is failing as it is trying to execute the command for the second DataGridView which would be in your second tab.

Comment: @webstackoverload did you tried on FormShown?

Comment: @Angelo Exactly, but I try to make it for each grid..

Comment: @MiguelCarreira I try to excute it on form loading, automaticly, and not bind to any event

Comment: Controls contained in a tabpage are not created until the tabpage is shown, which includes databindings and so forth. Your second command `dataGridView2.ClearSelection()` cannot be executed because the control itself is not yet created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to clear the selection on the DataGridView on the Tab Control's SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
private void tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection(); 
  else if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
    dataGridView2.ClearSelection(); 
}
```

Another option you can try is through the `DataBindingComplete` [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete?view=netframework-4.8)

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
}


private void dataGridView2_DataBindingComplete(object sender,
    DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
}
```

This will essentially clear the DataGridView's selection once the data has been loaded and bound.